# how to install pkg-config on ec2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, pip, pkg-config

From my ec2 instance, I am trying to run a python script that requires html5-parse. When I try running `python3 -m pip install html5_parser` , I get,

```
Collecting html5_parser
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a6/78/6a80c13be6c02fd2fb615b473a6ceff5b28bafca184f428ab197f677fd7a/html5-parser-0.4.9.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libxml-2.0' found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-bo946lpx/html5-parser/setup.py", line 79, in <module>
        include_dirs=include_dirs(),
      File "/tmp/pip-build-bo946lpx/html5-parser/build.py", line 94, in include_dirs
        return [x[2:] for x in pkg_config('libxml-2.0', '--cflags-only-I')]
      File "/tmp/pip-build-bo946lpx/html5-parser/build.py", line 76, in pkg_config
        val = subprocess.check_output([PKGCONFIG, pkg] + list(args)).decode('utf-8')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
        output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pkg-config', 'libxml-2.0', '--cflags-only-I']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-bo946lpx/html5-parser/
```

How can I install pkg-config on ubuntu so that I can finally install html5-parser?

Answer (score 1):

`html5-parser` can be installed through `apt` in Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-html5-parser
```

Answer (score 1):

For `html5_parser` you need `lxml`. So start at
https://lxml.de/installation.html#requirements :

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
```

For the rest see https://html5-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#unix :

```
pip install --no-binary lxml html5-parser
```